# every 20th occurence formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table and in column T and U, I have to calculate Mean and Standard Deviation

```
T8 = AVERAGE(OFFSET($C$8,(ROW()-ROW($C$8))*20,,20))


U8 = =STDEV.S(OFFSET($C$8,(ROW()-ROW($C$8))*20,,20))
```

This calculates fine, The difficulty I am having is, I need help tweaking this formula in a way that if data in next 20 rows are available, then only calculate

currently if the data is in 18 rows, its still calculating which gives me incorrect data

But want the formula to retrieve data , If there are data in 20 rows complete in Column C

Please advise

[image]

Comment: Test to see if the number of populated rows is = to 20, if not don’t calculate.

Comment: Use countifs to calculate how many occurences you have found up to the cell you are at